# Does invulnerability work in Sacrifice room?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

As I remember, in the old version of Binding of Isaac using items like **Book Of Shadows**, **My Little Unicorn**, or **The Gamekid** when passing over the spikes will render the player invulnerable to the spikes and quickly spawn the chest.

Does this "trick" still work in Rebirth?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must actually take damage to get loot from a Sacrifice room. You can walk on spikes as much as you want when you're invulnerable, but you won't get anything from it.

- Seed: **Y7CN SD87** (adjacent to start are [Holy Mantle](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Holy_Mantle) and Sacrifice room).
- [Video](http://youtu.be/NYXyJPw6jqE?t=21m43s) (shows [Callus](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Callus))

Comment: Yap, I've tried using The Chariot tarot card. Anyway, your anwser is right.